# How can I make my windows "burn" when I close them?

Tags: settings, compiz

I have **CompizConfig Settings Manager** installed, but I don't know how to make windows **burn** when I close them. How can I make this so?

Comment: Do you use gnome or kde?

Comment: This is my absolute favorite animation.

Comment: I use gnome. Thank you everyone for your answers!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

- Install **CompizConfig Settings
  Manager**, and
  **Compiz-Plugins-Extra**.

  `sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

  - Warning: [What are some of the issues with CCSM and why would I want to avoid it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/80589/what-are-some-of-the-issues-with-ccsm-and-why-should-i-not-use-it)

  `sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins-extra`
- Launch **CompizConfig Settings
  Manager** by searching from the dash
  in **Unity**, or **Preferences >
  CompizConfig Settings Manager** in
  **Ubuntu Classic**.
- Enable **Animations**, and
  **Animations Add-On**.

[image]

- Open **Animations**, and switch to
  the **Close Animation** tab.

[image]

- Double-click the first item in the
  list.

[image]

- A new window will appear, change the
  **Close Effect** to **Burn**.

[image]

*Please make sure you have the cellphone number of the nearest Fire Brigade available, because your system is about to catch fire... literally.*

Comment: To get the "Animation Add-On" category, you also have to install the compiz-fusion-plugins-extra package.

Comment: The image you are requesting does not exist or is no longer available.

Comment: Note that this may not work in 12.10 or 13.04 because of a [bug in Compiz](https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1069112) ([more](http://askubuntu.com/questions/289402/extra-animation-plugins-are-missing-in-compizconfig-settings-manager-ubuntu-13)).

Answer (score 1):

OK first you need to install the "CompizConfig Settings Manager" either go to the Ubuntu Software Centre and install the Advanced Desktop Effects Settings (CCSM),

or use the command:

`sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager`

When that is done go to the System > Preferences and start the CompizConfig-settings Manager

Go to the Effects section and enable the Animations Add-on.

You can then go into the Effect settings by clicking on the name to the right of the check box, under the Burn heading are all the options to tweak the animation. Hours of pointless fun playing with this.

Comment: "Hours of pointless fun playing with this".  Hours?  Try days.

Answer (score 1):

Just do it from `Synaptic`

Search for `compiz-fusion-plugins-extra package`

When you see it just mark it for install and a few seconds and here you are 
all effects are shown up

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu MATE 20.04 the "Animations add on" is not under "Effects" I found it under **? Uncategorized**.

Clicking it will enable it and the rest of the instructions work just fine.

[image: Screenshot of CCSM window]