# Extra animation plugins are missing in CompizConfig Settings Manager! (Ubuntu 13.04)

Tags: compiz, 13.04

[image]
I installed **compiz-plugins-extra**, expecting to enable animation effects like explode and window blur. But the extra plug-ins aren't shown in CompizConfig Settings Manager. Is there any way to get them?

Comment: @Naveen - you have entered "animations add-on" into the filter - do you see the plugin by just entering "animation" ?

Comment: @fossfreedom The same issue occurs here (also a clean 13.04 install). Only standard "Animations" are showing up if I search for `Animations`

Comment: Ah, I thought `Animations` wasn't showing up. I think some effects were removed from Compiz last year, though I can't find anything about explode...

Comment: I think this is a bug (https://bugs.launchpad.net/compiz/+bug/1069112) - please can you confirm - looks like the devs have temporarily disabled the package since the plugins no longer compile.

Comment: @fossfreedom : It was there in Precise, but no longer exists in Raring. I marked that bug as it affects me... So the fix is coming in Compiz 9.10 right? Will it land on Raring? What shall I do to this bounty? I'm totally screwed up! hlp! x(

Comment: Is it OK to try Compiz 9.10 from here? : https://launchpad.net/~smspillaz/+archive/compiz-experimental

Comment: That similarly has a "dummy package" - so no, its not yet fixed.  I'll refund your bounty and close this since its a confirmed bug.

Answer (score 2):

`compiz-plugin-extras` is a transitional dummy package. It does **not** contain the plugin(s) that you're looking for. It's more or less an empty package, only there to ensure a clean upgrade.

You will need to install the `compiz-plugins` package. (Ubuntu 13.04 does not install this package - it only installs the `compiz-plugin-defaults` package.)

After installing the `compiz-plugins` package, use CompizConfig Settings Manager to enable/disable and/or to change the default configuration of the extra plugin(s) that came with the package.

Logout, login to make Compiz use the new plugin(s) and changed settings.

Comment: Sorry Frank... compiz-plugins is already installed :( I even re-installed it.

Comment: @Naveen: I understand. You were looking for eye candy.

Comment: + vote for your effort.... tnx